# How to use text file reading/writing in server side of ASP.net web page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file, google-maps

I'm trying to run this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        DosyadanOku("c:\\sucdefteri.txt");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void DosyadanOku(string sucdefteri)
    {
        StreamReader dosyaOku = new StreamReader(@"C:\\sucdefteri.txt");

            string metin;
            metin = dosyaOku.ReadLine();

            string kesme = "\t";
            char[] b = kesme.ToCharArray();
            string[] satirlar = metin.Split(b);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", satirlar[2]);


        dosyaOku.Close();

}
}
```

at my server side of ASP.net page. This simply gets a line from sucdefteri.txt, then cuts a part of it and passes it to client side of page with

**Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", satirlar[2]);**. I mean it should, but it can't. If I try this file reading/cutting code as a console application, it's working fine, getting the part from the line and print it to console. But it's not working with this. And also if I add a code like this;

```
satirlar[2] ="'izmit'";
```

and then send it to client, it's working. So I think something is wrong with the file reading.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: The file you are trying to read on a Console App will work because of the Local Drive C:\ but on and or over the web the file path(s) on your local don't always match what's on the server you need to lookup how Server.MapPath() method works.. does this make sense

Comment: I changed my texts path and using Server.MapPath() now. But I can't read the file. That's my problem. I mean I'm using         StreamReader dosyaOku = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/sucdefteri.txt")); this now and it finds the path, but maybe it can't open or can't get any info from it for some reason. Maybe something is wrong with my file reading codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Server.MapPath(" ")`
like this

```
StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true);
    _testData.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text); // Write the file.
    _testData.Flush();
    _testData.Close(); // Close the instance of StreamWriter.
    _testData.Dispose(); // Dispose from memory.
```

Comment: What should I expect from this code block? I mean what it does? I don't understand this.

Comment: if u use Server.MapPath() then it creates files in server.if u not uses then it creates file in local machine.

Comment: I understand that but it's still not working. Can you check my reading codes, maybe something is wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't seem clear, but I believe you want to read/write a text file in asp.net. If yes, try this:

```
    public void WriteTextFile(String FileName)
    {
    TextWriter objTextWriter= new StreamWriter(FileName);
    objTextWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); //Writing current time in textfile
    objTextWriter.Close();
    }
    public String ReadTextFile(String FileName)
    {
    Textreader objTextReader= new StreamReader(FileName);
    String fileContent = objTextWriter.ReadLine();
    objTextReader.Close();
    return fileContent;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should avoid simply linking to resources without detailing the content here. If the link dies the answer is no longer useful.

Comment: Got it SO. Thanks. Well as shown in the link http://www.freedotnetapps.com/asp-net/how-to-export-data-from-asp-net-gridview-control-to-excel-spreadsheet/ you can use TextReader and TextWriter class from System.IO namespace, to read data from and write data to textfile.

Comment: Sorry, you have missed the point of my comment. You should edit your answer to include the source code that is provided in your linked resource. This will make your answer more valuable because people don't have to follow the link to get at it and move away from SO. It also means if the link breaks (which happens a lot), then the source code example will still be included here, and thus your answer may still be useful.

Comment: Much better thank you, again welcome to SO, if you need more help understanding about SO then be sure to check out http://www.stackoverflow.com/about and http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq